# Update app.config from WIX setup?

Tags: configuration, windows-services, wix, installation

I am trying Wix 3.6 and this is how it looks right now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="myappINSTALLDIR" Name="myapp5Service">
        <Component Id="SampleServiceComponent" DiskId="1" Guid="6f51c0f3-776c-4aec-a200-1f199352c6c3" Win64="yes">
          <File Id="myapp5.WindowsService.exe" Name="myapp5.WindowsService.exe" Source="$(var.myapp.WindowsService.TargetDir)\myapp5.WindowsService.exe" KeyPath='yes'/>
          ...

          <ServiceInstall Id="InstallmyappService" DisplayName="myappService" Name="myapp5.WindowsService.exe" Description="myapp 5 Service - För effektivare och enklare operationsplanering" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" />
          <ServiceControl Id="ControlmyappService" Name="myapp5.WindowsService.exe" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
        </Component>
    </Directory>
</Directory>


<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Image\myappTopBanner.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Image\myappDialogBackground.bmp" />

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="myappINSTALLDIR" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix_myapp.WindowsService" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="SampleServiceComponent" />
</Feature>
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="SampleServiceComponent.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
</Product>
```

Now I need to add a dialog to the Wix setup where one appSetting and one baseadress(WCF) is set to the app.config. This most be done before the installation becouse it will decide the name of the Windows Service that the Wix is installning.

And exampel would be great!

Edit 1:

```
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Image\myappTopBanner.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Image\myappDialogBackground.bmp" />

<Property Id="SERVICEADDRESS" Value="http://serviceaddress"/>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="myappINSTALLDIR" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

<util:XmlFile Id="UpdateBaseAddress"
  Action="setValue"
  File="$(var.myapp.WindowsService.TargetDir)\myapp5.WindowsService.exe.config"
  SelectionLanguage="XPath"
  Permanent="yes"
  ElementPath="/configuration/applicationSettings/ServiceName"
  Name="baseAddress" Value="[SERVICEADDRESS]" />

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix_myapp.WindowsService" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="SampleServiceComponent" />
</Feature>
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="SampleServiceComponent.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
</Product>
```

Answer (score 10):

You could add in a reference to the WixUtilExtension.dll to the installer project, then use XmlFile to update the app.config like:

```
<Property Id="SERVICEADDRESS" Value="http://serviceaddress"/>

<util:XmlFile Id="UpdateBaseAddress" 
  Action="setValue" 
  File="[DirApplication]$(var.app.config)"
  SelectionLanguage="XPath" 
  Permanent="yes"
  ElementPath="/configuration/applicationSettings/...."
  Name="baseAddress" Value="[SERVICEADDRESS]" />
```

Note that you'll need to set the directory and the name of the .config file (you could just use $(var.*ProjectName*.TargetFileName).config which *should* work it out for you automatically

Comment: Thanks! Pleas see Edit 1. I have updated my project but I get the following exception : The Product element contains an unexpected child elenent. Also note that its important that the user sets this information to the config file before the installation of the service is made(It decides the name of the installed Windows Service).

Comment: @SnowJim, according to docs [`XmlFile`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm) must reside in `Component` element.

Comment: Note that to use Daniel's answer you'll need to define `util` by adding `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` to your root `<Wix />` element.

Comment: If this is your app setting `<appSettings><add key="MyAppSetting" value="OldValue"/></appSettings>`, then the proper escaping would be `ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='MyAppSetting'[\]]" Name="value" Value="NewValue"`

Comment: How does this handle upgrades?

Comment: What is not clear is when this change is triggered. Will this happen only at the end of the install process?