# WiX alternatives?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have tried to build a MSI package for my Windows Service with WiX for a couple of days but have big problems to get it the way I need.

The documentation is very bad and then XML structure just dont feels structured. I really don't see how they could have been doing a worse job at version 3.6.

I dont want to invest all my time in the MSI package, instead I need my time in dev of the main application.

So the questions is, what MSI builder should I use If I need:

- Set app.config settings during installation
- Install Windows Service
- Start Windows Service
- Simple install/uninstall

Thats really all I need

Comment: I've been involved in installation and deployment for about 5 years and I feel that WiX is far superior to the other tools out there. Like Simon says below, WiX forces you to have a good understanding of how Windows Installer works, which is not a bad thing. That said, there is a ton of online documentation and resources for InstallShield, so if you think it's worth the cost you may try them.

Comment: Its ironic because WiX is very well thought of and in my experience is stronger than a lot of stuff out there. I have cursed VS Setup projects for years because their functional limitations. My conclusion is that there is no silver bullet - any route you choose to go will contain some cost, even if you buy a product off-the-shelf. Incidentally custom action dlls will work for you to do what you want to do, either using VS Setup or Wix, but you *still* need to invest the time writing the code!

Comment: I'd be willing to spend an hour on a WebEx with you to give you a primer to help you get traction. I'm also available for consulting.  A simple installer for a service takes me about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WiX can do all those things fairly easily (I have applications that do that and some that I use WiX to install). Problem is you have to have a pretty good understanding of Windows Installer to use WiX, as it does not really hide any of the detail from you.

The obviously alternative is [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) (They have a LE version that comes with VS2012 apparently, using VS2012 but not that) and Express is relatively reasonably priced.

You also may want to check out [InstallAware](http://www.installaware.com), but I have not had good experiences with them personally when I have looked at them.

I have also been told that [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) is usable, though I have not used it myself personally.

Comment: The main Problem of Wix is, that it has noe useful documentation. Instead of adding features they might spend an hour or two documenting what they have done....

Comment: If you think that its fairly easily done you are more then welcome to help me out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967551/update-app-config-from-wix-setup

Comment: Advanced Installer has a lot of online free tutorials and a detailed documentation that you can use. Also, a very active community can be reached on its forums: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/ . Its easy to use GUI I think is also what you want, as you can create a project in no time and you don't need to spend to much time to learn using it.

Answer (score 2):

A list and description of other installation products as well as Wix: [What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)

And a link to some Wix quick-start suggestions (similar articles):

- [Wix generate single component id for entire tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548374/wix-generate-single-component-id-for-entire-tree/22550256#22550256)
- [**WiX Quick Start Tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)