# how to create installer package

Tags: c, windows, installation

I have developed a program which retrieve data from windows registry and some other functionality along with it.
Now I want to make an installer and distribute it.(I have an option of distributing .exe but I don't want to use it)

now my problem is how can I make an installer like we get of professional software.
exp-antivirus,adobe etc

please help..

Thanks
Raghav

Comment: Hello Gangadhar the URL that u provided is giving error...

Answer (score 1):

Microsofts currently preferred way (please note that this is subject to change) is WiX (Windows Installer Xml).

http://wix.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like scripting in WiX or don't have the time to learn you always have [these alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972961/wix-alternatives).