# Replacing element in app.config from external config file using WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, app-config

I am 100% new to WiX but I have to start off with a advanced issue and I have virtually no idea if that is even possible. I have an out of-the-box WiX project in front of me that creates a msi installer for me. But I want to deploy an external config file with it, from which a specific element will be inserted into the app.config within the msi file. I need this because I need to have custom behavior on different target machines without rebuilding for every one.
Does anyone have some kind of opinion on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update app.config from WIX setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967551/update-app-config-from-wix-setup)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/290374/656243